Edges of Widgets in CSSGrid do not align in higher resolutions
I am using a CSSGrid in SAPUI5 to display a grid of widgets. For some reason, when I view the Grid on a 1080p Monitor, all of the edges do align perfectly. If I view it on a 1440p Monitor or higher res, the gaps between the widgets get bigger and some of the edges do not align anymore (see attached screenshot).
Widget Grid
The column span of all the widgets is 3, except for the one causing trouble where it's 2.
If i set the column span to 3 then the edges marked in the middle do align, but the one marked on the left side still do not align.
SAPUI5 version is 1.84.17
CCSGrid XML:
<grid:CSSGrid id="dashboardWidgetsContainer"
                  gridTemplateColumns="repeat(12, 1fr)"
                  gridTemplateRows="max-content"
                  gridAutoFlow="Row">
</grid:CSSGrid>

XML of the Widget causing trouble:
<mvc:View controllerName="" 
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"  
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    class="dashboard-seamless-content-widget">
    <l:BlockLayout background="Dashboard" class="sapUiBlockLayoutKeepFontSize">
        <l:BlockLayoutRow>
            <l:BlockLayoutCell class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
                <Panel expanded="true">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text=""/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <content>
                        <VBox>
                            <core:Fragment fragmentName="" />
                        </VBox>
                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
        </l:BlockLayoutRow>
    </l:BlockLayout>
</mvc:View>


Decreasing the padding of the CSSGrid does fix the problem for the outer edge in higher resolutions, but makes it so the edge does not align in lower resolutions.

Decreasing the width of the CSSGrid does fix the problem but causes a big empty space on the right side



Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? . You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.
